# How to prevent text style defaults during CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w3vXb/2/)

How do I prevent the text weight form changing to bolder during the transition? The end result both ways is fine, but *during* the transition, the text gets bolder. This happens with the elements after the element hovered. E.g. if you hover the second event on the timeline, the first one is not affected but the second itself and the third are.

HTML

```
<div class="timeline">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <span class="date">Week 1</span>Event 1
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="date">Week 2</span>Event 2
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="date">Week 3</span>Event 3
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ol {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 100px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #24ad9e;
}
ol::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 10px solid #24ad9e;
    right: -10px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid #24ad9e;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.timeline ol li {
    position: relative;
    top: -76px;
    left:-50px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;   
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    font: 14px "Lato" Helvetica Arial;
}
.timeline ol li::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: -29px;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid #24ad9e;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.date {
    color: #000;
    display: block; 
    margin-top: -17px;
}

/* Hover effects */

.timeline ol li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #28e;
}
.timeline ol li:hover::before {
    /*top: 1px;
    left: -29px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* transitions */
.timeline ol li::before, .timeline ol li:hover::before {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Don't transition `all`...just transition the properties you WANT to transition.

Comment: @Paulie_D targeting `transform` didn't help. Also, the selectors are only for the `::before` and not the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS backface-visibility property to solve this problem. Refer to this [Link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/)

Comment: This works, thanks. Question, does it matter if I do `* { backface... }` or does it have to be class-specific?

Comment: My suggestion use backface class specific.